# C++ append path with file name

Tags: c++, string, fstream, dev-c++

I am trying to append the path in which my file is saved along with the name of file. Below is my code

```
int main() 
{
cout << "Please enter the name of the file: ";
string fileName;
getline(cin, fileName);
ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Faisal\\Desktop\\Programs\\"+fileName.c_str(), ios::in);
string line;
for (int count = 1; !file.eof(); ++count) 
{
    getline(file, line);
    cout << line << endl;
    if (count % 24 == 0) system("Pause");
}
   system("Pause");
}
```

Below is my error

> [Error] invalid operands of types 'const char [34]' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'

**Update 1**

As per @drescherjm comment. I have update my code

```
int main() 
{
cout << "Please enter the name of the file: ";
string fileName;
string pathName = "C:\\Users\\Faisal\\Desktop\\Programs\\";
getline(cin, fileName);
string fileToOpen = pathName + fileName;
ifstream file(fileToOpen.c_str());

if (!file){

// There was an error so display an error

// message and end the PROGRAM.

cout << "Error opening " << fileName << endl;

exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
string line;
for (int count = 1; !file.eof(); ++count) 
{
    getline(file, line);
    cout << line << endl;
    if (count % 24 == 0) system("Pause");
}
   system("Pause");
}
```

My file is not opening and the output is

```
Please enter the name of the file: ali
Error opening ali
```

Comment: There is no + operator for c-strings. Your code is attempting to add pointers.

Comment: @drescherjm no  I want to open my file from the path

Comment: Do the string concatenation with the std::string variable. The + will work there.

Comment: @drescherjm `ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Faisal\\Desktop\\Programs\\"+ std::string(fileName.c_str()), ios::in);` giving me `[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::basic_string<char>, const openmode&)'`

Comment: `fileName = "C:\\Users\\Faisal\\Desktop\\Programs\\" + filename; ifstream file(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);`

Comment: Not working. The file is not opening

Comment: @drescherjm see my update 1

Comment: Maybe the filename you typed does not exist. Be careful if you have the hide extensions for known file types enabled in the OS file explorer. This can cause a lot of confusion. Related: [https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-enable-hidden-file-extensions-in-Windows.html](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-enable-hidden-file-extensions-in-Windows.html)

Comment: Are you sure the file isn't `ali.txt`?